# Multicombo box drops down to other rows while scrolling down the table

Tags: sapui5, scrollable

Before scrolling down
[image]

After scrolling down
[image]

As you can see 1,1,2 has shifted down in the ui

I have a `sap.ui.table` and I have a add row Button which will add more rows to the table.

Also there is a column in the table which has MultiComboBox. Now if I have added many rows at once and the table becomes vertically scrollable. So when I scroll down, the MultiComboBox starts dropping down to other rows, though it does not affect the model which I have bind to the table. How do I prevent this for happening?

```
        <t:Table selectionMode="MultiToggle" columnHeaderHeight="32px" fixedColumnCount="2" visibleRowCount="{tasks>/noOfTasks}" id="taskTable"
            class="tasktable" rows="{path: 'tasks>/task' , sorter: [{ path: 'taskNo',comparator:'.comparator.sortTask'}]}" noData="No Tasks" alternateRowColors="true">
            <t:toolbar>
                <OverflowToolbar>
                    <Title text="Pending Tasks"></Title>
                    <ToolbarSpacer/>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://request" tooltip="Edit tasks" press="editTask"/>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://full-screen" tooltip="show detailed info of the selected task" press="getDetailedInfo"/>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://add" text="Add Tasks" class="addTaskButton" press="addNewTask"></Button>
                </OverflowToolbar>
            </t:toolbar>
            <t:columns>
                <t:Column width="5rem" hAlign="Center" class="cellBorderLeft cellBorderRight">
                    <Label required="true" text="Task No."/>
                    <t:template>
                        <Text text="{tasks>taskNo}"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="10rem" class="cellBorderRight">
                    <Label required="true" text="Task Name"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <Input value="{tasks>taskName}" editable="{= !(${tasks>exists})}"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="18rem" class="cellBorderRight">
                    <Label required="true" text="Task Details"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <Input value="{tasks>taskDetails}" editable="{= !(${tasks>exists})}"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column class="cellBorderRight" width="14rem">
                    <Label required="true" text="Assigned To"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <HBox>
                            <Input value="{tasks>assignedTo}" placeholder="Please Enter the NTID only" editable="{= !(${tasks>exists})}"></Input>
                            <core:Icon src="sap-icon://search" visible="{= !(${tasks>exists})}" class="searchEmp" press="searchForEmployees"></core:Icon>
                        </HBox>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column class="cellBorderRight" width="12rem">
                    <Label required="true" text="Priority"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <HBox width="99%" class="priorityBox">
                            <Select width="100%" selectedKey="{tasks>priority}" enabled="{= !(${tasks>exists}) || ${tasks>edit} === true}"
                                items="{path:'tasks>priorities',templateShareable:false}">
                                <core:Item key="{tasks>value}" text="{tasks>value}"/>
                                <core:Item key="{tasks>value}" text="{tasks>value}"/>
                                <core:Item key="{tasks>value}" text="{tasks>value}"/>
                            </Select>
                        </HBox>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column class="cellBorderRight" width="10rem">
                    <Label required="true" text="Start Date"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <DatePicker placeholder="Enter date" value="{tasks>startDate}" editable="{= !(${tasks>exists})}" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
                            displayFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column class="cellBorderRight" width="10rem">
                    <Label required="true" text="End Date"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <DatePicker placeholder="Enter date" value="{tasks>endDate}" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
                            editable="{= !(${tasks>exists}) || ${tasks>edit} === true}" displayFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column class="cellBorderRight" width="8rem">
                    <Label text="Status"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <Text text="{tasks>status}"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column class="cellBorderRight" width="11rem">
                    <Label required="true" text="Module"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <Input value="{tasks>module}" enabled="{= !(${tasks>exists})}"></Input>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column class="cellBorderRight" width="12rem">
                    <Label text="Dependency"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <HBox>
                            <Input value="{tasks>dependency}" editable="{= !(${tasks>exists})}"
                                visible="{= ${tasks>exists} === true &amp;&amp; ${tasks>edit} === false}"/>
                            <MultiComboBox id="dependents" visible="{= !(${tasks>exists}) || ${tasks>edit} === true}" selectionChange="onSelectChange"
                                items="{ path: 'dependents>/dependents',templateShareable:false}">
                                <core:Item key="{dependents>taskID}" text="{dependents>taskNo}"
                                    enabled="{= ${tasks>dependency}.toString().indexOf(${dependents>taskNo}) ===-1}"/>
                            </MultiComboBox>
                        </HBox>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column hAlign="Center" class="cellBorderRight" width="22rem">
                    <Label text="Notes"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <Input value="{tasks>notes}" editable="{= !(${tasks>exists}) || ${tasks>edit} === true}"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column class="cellBorderRight" width="6rem">
                    <Label text="Attachment"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <VBox>
                            <UploadCollection maximumFilenameLength="5555" maximumFileSize="10"
                                visible="{= ${tasks>attachmentAdded} === false &amp;&amp; ${tasks>exists} === false || ${tasks>edit} === true}" multiple="true"
                                change="onChange" fileType="txt,doc,png,jpg" uploadComplete="onUploadCompleted" class="taskAttach" instantUpload="false" mode="MultiSelect"
                                app:taskNo="{tasks>taskNo}"></UploadCollection>
                            <core:Icon src="sap-icon://attachment" app:files="{tasks>attachments/files}"
                                visible="{= ${tasks>attachmentAdded} === true &amp;&amp; ${tasks>exists} === true &amp;&amp; ${tasks>edit} === false}" press="downloadFile"
                                app:taskNo="{tasks>taskNo}"/>
                        </VBox>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
            </t:columns>
        </t:Table>
```

Comment: It will not affect the model as it relates to the table and not the data. When selecting however you do have access to the items in your model that have been selected - but you probably know that? Please clarify further in case I have misunderstood.

Comment: It is just happening like that in ui..so it is reflecting as some error

Comment: perhaps if you look in the console of your browser you can see what the error is?

Comment: Hi, I had also some table issues with a select box.... not very similar too yours but maybe this fixet it also for you.
long edition: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2458
short explaination: try to set css class sapUiSizeCozy to body (<body class="sapUiSizeCozy") or if I remeber right it also works if you define this class to your table.

Comment: @Bernard I'm not getting any error

Comment: @DubZ No.My issue is different.I have updated my question with the images.Please have a look

Comment: @aeshnaKashyap I know that ur issue is different. But nevertheless did you check if the css class will change something ?

Comment: i better understand your problem now. When you add a row are you cloning an empty item and adding this to your model?

Comment: @Bernard yes..i 'm adding a new item to the model

Comment: @DubZ I have not added any css class for table rows or the multicombo box

Comment: @aeshnaKashyap man common please. read my text. just try to set class="sapUiSizeCozy" your html <body> or in xml view the table and tell me the results

Comment: @DubZ i did that..it did not make any difference

Comment: do you clone something or do you create a new empty object and add it to the collection? - I would have though the latter would have ensured no multi-selects.